# Swift manipulating objects inside a for loop

Tags: swift

I am trying to assign a `Shot` instance to my `Action` instance inside a for loop, but for some reason it's not taking. When I set a breakpoint inside the loop, I can see that the code is being executed, but after inspecting the `Action` objects after the loop runs, none of them have `Shot`s associated with them. What am I doing wrong?

```
var i = 0
let shots = getShots() as! [Shot]
for action in action_sequence{
    if action.type == "shot" && i < Int(shots.count){
        action.shot = shots[i] //->Breakpoint set. This code is being executed.
        i += 1
    }
}
//->Breakpoint set and none of the action instances have shots defined.
```

Where `action_sequence` is an array of `Action` objects defined as :

```
@objc class Action: NSObject {
    var shot:Shot?
    var name = ""
    var complete = false
    var type = "shot"
}
```

### Edit

I often try to simplify my code before posting it on SO to make it easier for others. But apparently simplifying my code removed the problem somehow. Here's what's really going on:

```
@interface Session : NSObject
@property float average_score;
...
-(int)shotCount;
-(NSArray*)getShots;
@end


@interface Shot : NSObject
@property float score, x, y;
@property long long time_stamp;
...


class Drill: NSObject {
    ...
    var action_sequence = [DrillAction]() 


class DrillReviewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSourc{
    var drill : Drill?
    var session: Session()
    ...

    override func refreshView(){
        super.refreshView()
        //load the drill sequence with the shots from the session.

        var i = 0
        let shots = self.session.getShots() as! [Shot]
        for action in self.drill!.action_sequence{
            if action.type == "shot" && i < Int(self.session.shotCount()){
                action.shot = shots[i]
                i += 1
            }
        }    
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use a struct instead if it's a model object (Action) ??

Comment: Not related to the issue but why do you create an `Int` from an `Int` (`.count`)?

Comment: @vadian the _entire_ code is silly

Comment: What happens if you type `print (shots)` before the for loop?

Comment: @matt I know I just wanted to point out the silliest part ;)

Comment: @vadian I think the counting variable itself is the silliest part. :)))

Comment: @matt I surrender, you are right.

Comment: @matt Let's be constructive here.
@vadian Thanks. I used to have `session.getShotCount()` which returned an Int32, so I needed to change it to Int.
@Umar I'm still trying to get used to swift. I'll look into how to do it with a struct.
@PranavKasetti I see all the shots as I would expect.

Comment: The counting variable is because the `shots` array is a different size than the `action_sequence`

Comment: Please don't be too hard on someone new to the language. If you guys have better suggestions, please show that in an answer. OP, from your question we cant see anything wrong. Please try printing action_sequence and share that. Also check count of shots.

Comment: In Swift there are more sophisticated ways to restrict the number of iterations for example `for (index, action) in action_sequence.enumerated() where index < shots.count`. `index` is the equivalent to your `i` index variable.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat little trick. Imagine I have an `action_sequence` with 3 actions and a shots array with 2 shots. And the second action has `action.type = "run"`. Won't I end up assigning the first and second `action`s the two shots, when I really want to be assigning the 1st and 3rd `action`s `shot`s?

Comment: @ChaseRoberts You are not yet grappling with the fact that no one can reproduce the problem you originally posed.

Comment: Patience @matt, I _am_ grappling with it, I just don't have anything to say about it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing, in your question, the cause of the issue. It lies elsewhere. It could be how you are testing, or it could be something about `shots`.

In a situation like this, test by reducing the problem to something simpler, like this (you didn't choose to reveal what a Shot is, so I just made something up):

```
@objc class Action: NSObject {
    var shot:Shot?
    var name = ""
    var complete = false
    var type = "shot"
}
@objc class Shot : NSObject {}

let action_sequence = [Action()]
var i = 0
let shots = [Shot()]
for action in action_sequence{
    if action.type == "shot" && i < Int(shots.count){
        action.shot = shots[i]
        i += 1
    }
}
print(action_sequence[0].shot) // it is a Shot, not nil
```

That worked, so your basic code must work. (Your code is also rather silly, since you could have written it much more compactly, without the counting variable `i`. But that isn't what you asked about.)